# Where can I see all the YouTube photos/pictures posts that I liked

Tags: youtube

I can see my comments, liked videos, etc. But I did not find anywhere to see my liked photo posts.

Where can I find them?

Answer (score 1):

First open the "YouTube", then click on the "three horizontal lines", then click on "history", then "community". Now you can see the posts which you opened, liked and disliked in YouTube, here you can see a bold word "**post**" click on that, you can see the post easily.

Answer (score 0):

Okayy so, if you’re on your phone go to your browser and search « YouTube.com » then switch to desktop mode and when you’re on desktop mode, click on the three horizontal lies next to the YouTube icon, click on « history », then on the right side, there will be an option to switch from « watch history » to « community », click on community and it will show you thé community posts you’ve liked.

(You may not be able to click on them and view the pictures again, but you can see which accounts you liked the posts from and search the account name on YouTube. Just go to their account and look through their community posts it’s gonna be somewhere there, it won’t be hard to find if it’s a recent post.)

~UrFavoriteIdiot